# How do I connect random users with Websockets?

Tags: websocket

I have made an up and running chat application using websockets. I have a VPS where I want to host this application on. The application is working all fine, but it would be great if I could connect two random users (now it is like 1 chatroom, where a shitload of people could chat in). How do you keep track of who's online? Should I check with AJAX every x seconds? SetTimeOut would overload my server, I'm afraid...How does Omegle do that? I am thinking of solutions, but the AJAX solution is the only one I can think of, but I don't want to overload the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect two users directly with WebSockets, but you may with WebRTC data channels : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/

With WebSockets, both need to be connected to the server. Then your app should send messages to the server indicating to which room are you talking with, or to which chat user. When a user disconnects, the server should inform the users with common chat rooms or private chats opened that such user disconnected.

The server is the one responsible of broadcasts the messages of a user the right places, keep track of which users are in which chat rooms, etc...

So rather than send just text messages, send JSON objects with more data like:

```
{ cls: "join", room: "whatever", nick: "vtortola" }
{ message: "hi", cls: "msg", room: "whatever" }
```

And the server should send events to the clients as well informing of users joining/leaving and also the messages.

I wrote a [very simple chat](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/blob/master/samples/RxWebSocketChat/WebSocketChatClientMVC/Content/Scripts/chat.js), but maybe the event handling could give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a real chat system, you should use a chat protocol, e.g., XMPP (there are others).  This gives you deeper chat semantics that using low-level WebSocket, which is a transport protocol, not really an application-level protocol.  If you want to chat over the web, then you need XMPP to use either HTTP (using BOSH, which is HTTP-based) or WebSocket (search for XMPP over WebSocket).